# JAVA - What are the differences between these?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

There are two ways I know of to create Threads.

1.

```
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
      //do something;
     }
    };
```

2. ```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
      //do something;
     }
    });
   ```

What I am asking is that, are there any differences in these methods, like which one is more efficient regarding Memory usage, CPU usage (if there is any difference), etc.

Comment: basically, your question is: should I extend Thread, or should I implement Runnable. Unless you plan on altering default behavior of the Thread class (which in about 99% you really don't want to do) do NOT extend Thread, always go for an implementation of Runnable.

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question!

Comment: Please read it properly. Moreover, both are same just you are using an interface and class.

Comment: @PeterParker it should, actually. you are asking the difference between an anonymous class extending Thread, and an anonymous class implementing Runnable, that link is exactly what you should read.

Comment: The memory and CPU usage will be exactly the same (maybe a difference of a few bytes on the memory side, but it is completely insignificant compared to the size of the JVM for example). Use the second construct, it's cleaner.

Comment: These days (Java 8 and later), `new Thread(() -> { /*do something*/ })` would be better. Or the *method reference* equivalent. Both saves the creation of an anonymous class.

Comment: @Dioxin Both are anonymous classes.

Comment: What does this 1uestion have to do with swing? Please remove the swing tag.